# want to take a week PTO 'After' 3 weeks notice, is this acceptable or crazy?

Tags: notice-period, health, benefits, time-off

I gave notice 1 weeks ago. Being nice, I agreed to remain for 3 weeks instead of 2 weeks, so 2 more week remaining. Now, I've decide I want to take 1 week vacation between jobs.

Not being one to throw away money, I don't want to pay for health care should I need it during that week of vacation, which is actually not unlikely given the vacation will be more active than usual. This would cost about $1000 as it requires paying for the entire month, plus would be an annoyance to do all the paperwork.

Current employer's health insurance stops immediately after last day of work and doesn't continue until end of the month. Next employer's health insurance starts immediately upon first day of work with no delay. So really I'm just worried about the 1 week in between.

I've asked my current manager if I can have my official end date be 1 week after the 3 week notice period ends; I have sufficient PTO to cover. She said it's impossible.

I'm kind of bummed, given I gave 3 weeks notice and have helped out multiple times on weekends without being reimbursed the time; and now, the one favor I ask is rejected. I feel like all she would have to do was make a phone call to HR, and maybe resubmit some form. Am I crazy to ask for 1 week of pto before my last date, or is this really my manager being amateur?

This is a large company with an HR department in San Fransisco and is overall a professional place to work.

Comment: At this point, you're basically asking to be paid for an extra week for doing nothing of value to the company. I can see why they'd refuse.

Comment: What's the law about PTO there? Does your contract say anything about it? In some places you could expect to be given money in lieu, but perhaps not in California.

Comment: VTC as off topic since this essentially depends on local labor law and/or company policy. I've worked for employers who would either pay out PTO as a lump sum or allow "time off" during the notice period, and others where you forfeit your PTO the moment you resigned.

Comment: Not a given they will cash out your PTO.  Unless a value is assigned in the contract they may assign a  value of zero.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm kind of bummed, given I gave 3 weeks notice and have helped out multiple times on weekends without being reimbursed the time; and now, the one favor I ask is rejected

You expected fairness and loyalty and thoughtfulness from a corporation. That's a great mistake to learn from, particularly since this mistake cost you nothing. Don't make that mistake again.

> Am I crazy to ask for 1 week of pto before my last date?

Yes.

Companies have policies in place to prevent shenanigans like this because shenanigans like this are not in the interest of the company.

Now, let me give you a contrasting case from my life. I was feeling burned out, I told my employer that I wanted to take a year off, and that I could afford to do so, and that I was therefore giving notice, and so on.  They very kindly offered to keep my benefits turned on for an extra month *because they spent that month trying to induce me to change my mind and stay*. Note the differences: I didn't ask, I didn't expect it, I wasn't heading to a competitor, and they felt it was in their interests to do so. It didn't work, but I was very appreciative that they tried.

This is not your situation. You're a short timer who is now effectively working for the competition. Be happy they didn't escort you out the door with your stuff in a box when they found out you had accepted an offer from a competitor.  There are plenty of companies where that is the policy, and it's a sensible policy.  **You are a security liability and a hazard to the morale of your coworkers right now and you're doing no useful long term work**.  They have every incentive to kick you to the curb. Be thankful that they're keeping you employed for two more weeks. They have no incentive to go above and beyond.

> I don't want to pay for health care should I need it during that week of vacation

Don't pay for health care during that week. If you get injured, pay for it out of pocket. If the expense is *catastrophic* then *you can sign up for COBRA retroactively up to sixty days after your last day and your coverage extends backwards in time to the day you left your job*.  It's expensive but it is cheaper than catastrophic care.

Do not take my word for it; I am not an expert on COBRA.  Today would be a great day to research COBRA and learn for yourself how the program works.

You're fine. Go enjoy your vacation, and try to not break any limbs.

Comment: Note fro future readers, COBRA is a US thing to extend your health care for a time after you leave with you picking up not only your costs but the part the company usually covers. It is very expensive.

Comment: Also check with your health care insurer, often health care is paid in advance by month and will continue to the end of the month.

Comment: @HLGEM: The question already states that the original poster has investigated that and found that it does not extend until the end of the month. (Moreover, this doesn't help if the proposed week of vacation falls at the start of a month.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not crazy, but their reaction is not unexpected.  You're leaving for a reason and if they weren't willing to compensate you for overtime, they're not likely to accommodate you in any way as you're heading out the door.

It's not crazy to ask, but it's not exactly the hallmark of sanity to expect a positive response with the track record they have with you.  If you're that concerned about needing healthcare during that week due to an active vacation, I'd cancel the vacation as you wouldn't want to start the first week of your new job with an injury.

Better to run through to the end of your current job with no issues.

Answer (score -1):

I don't suppose it's "crazy" to ask, but it doesn't surprise me at all that your manager says this is a no-go. The company can keep you for the next three weeks, pay out your remaining PTO, and be done. You're asking them to keep you for the next three weeks, pay your remaining PTO, *and* contribute their share to your health insurance for an extra week. I've never worked at a company where PTO could be used to artificially extend the employment period - if you're not coming back after your time off, the company has no reason to keep you on the books. What you're asking for only has an upside for you, and brings additional liabilities and expenses for your employer.

Comment: Not a given they will pay out the PTO.

Comment: @paparazzo California law requires that the employer pay out accrued but unused PTO to any employee who separates from the company, regardless of the reason for separation.

Comment: No idea about California, but in some jurisdictions the PTO payout is treated differently (lump sum vs salary) - so it can cost more for the company to pay the PTO as vacation than to simply pay out on departure.

Comment: If it's part of his employment contract that he is due the time, then he must be paid @paparazzo